# Version tags on questions involving upgrades

Tags: discussion, tags, best-practice

On questions where the person posting had upgraded their Ubuntu version (for example, from 11.04 to 11.10) prior to / while experiencing an issue, how should the version tags be properly handled? Should tags for both versions be left on, or just the tag for the version that was upgraded to?

I'm especially wondering how this to be handled in the case of upgrading to an LTS release, where they could have upgraded from one of two prior versions. For example, someone upgrading to 12.04 LTS might have upgraded from either 11.10 or 10.04. Should this difference then be noted in the tags, if it might make a difference in the solution they're looking for?

Comment: Note that I used 12.04 above just as an example; normally "Ubuntu+1" questions are not allowed. For the purposes of this discussion at this point in time, pretend it had already released, or imagine a scenario involving another LTS.